# Rails 3, How to get Application URL inside routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I thkink this is a easy question, but I didn't find the solution. 
In Rails, How can I get my application URL inside routes?

Something like:

```
get '/foo', to: redirect("http://whatheverurl.com/?bar=#{MY_APPLICATION_URL}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  match '/foo', :to => redirect { |params, request|
    "http://whatheverurl.com/?bar=#{request.env['HTTP_HOST']}"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
  match "/web_site", :to => proc { |env|
    [301, { 
      'Location' => "http://www.greenviewdata.com?from=#{env['HTTP_HOST']}" 
    }, ["Go here instead: http://www.greenviewdata.com?from=#{env['HTTP_HOST']}"]]
  }
```

Comment: What version of rails are you running?  I tested this on 3.2.2